# How do I import ES6 Module within a create-react-app without causing tests to fail?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app, es6-modules, ui5-webcomponents

When I follow the instructions found [here](https://sap.github.io/ui5-webcomponents/playground/tutorials/react/)

and add the import reference as they specify:

`import "@ui5/webcomponents/dist/Button";`

the application works fine and is able to import the button.
However, when I `npm run test`, I get an error:

`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module.`

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Do you use `react-scripts test` command? Unlike pure jest, react-scripts add some configuration on top, which makes imports working

Comment: yes, my package.json has "test": "react-scripts test jest-environment-happy-dom",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer was provided [here](https://github.com/SAP/ui5-webcomponents/issues/1176#issuecomment-583896275).

```
{
   "jest": {
      "transformIgnorePatterns": [
         "node_modules/(?!(@ui5|lit-html)).*\\.js$"
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it to: `"test": "react-scripts test --transformIgnorePatterns \"node_modules/(?!@codemirror)/\"",`